# WebSocket communication between services on GPC?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, websocket

I have 2 services that I hope to deploy to GCP. The services need to communicate with each other over the WebSocket protocol.

So far I've tried deploying the services to an App Engine Flexible instance, but looks like they can't establish a wss connection with each other.

Going through the GCP docs on the App Engine Flexible environment, I get the feeling that's not supported.

If that's the case, can you advice on what's the best way to do it using GCP?